# On Scala how do I pass parameters to file with sql statements and use sqlContext.sql?

Tags: sql, scala, apache-spark, dynamic

My sql query is long and stored in a file. I would like to make the `where`  clause dynamic by passing parameters. 
In scala I would like to execute this using spark `sqlcontext.sql` (queryfile). Please help.

```
val FromDate = "2019-02-25"

val sqlfile = fromFile("queryfile").getLines.mkString

val result = sqlContext.sql(sqlfile)
```

On the file I have:

```
Select col1, col2 from table1 where transdate = '${FromDate}'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's easy, use the replace method of scala:

```
val FromDate = "2019-02-25"
val s = "Select col1, col2 from table1 where transdate = '${FromDate}'"
val withParameters= s.replace("${FromDate}",FromDate )
println(withParameters)
val result = sqlContext.sql(withParameters)
```